# An alternative way of starting a sentence "Do you want a..."

Tags: american-english

An alternative way of starting a sentence "**Do you want** ...a shortcut to success in your business and life"

Comment: Hello, Dave. 'Alternative ways to say' questions are asking for writing / style advice, which is off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options:

1. **Would you like** a shortcut to success in your business and life?
2. **Are you looking for** a shortcut to success in your business and life?

You might also consider:

1. **Do you to strive for success** in your business and life?
2. **Do you aim at success** in your business and life?
3. **Do you seek success** in your business and life?